# zsh script that takes a variable number of arguments

Tags: shell-script, ssh, zsh

I have just (belatedly) discovered that I can ssh -t from one machine to another and run a command there.

The thought then took me that I should be able to come up with a script that tailed a log file (from a pair) on a machine by doing something like

```
ssh -t $1 ssh -t $2 tailf /pathtofile/$3/log.log
```

and indeed if I put in 1,2 and 3 by hand it works just fine.

My problem is that I may have 1,2 or 3 hosts to jump between to make this work.

How would I do this in zsh? I've done some digging and it looks as though shift may be my friend, but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not really a `zsh` user, I will write a `sh` solution (`zsh` *should* be able to execute it too).

The general gist is to create a list with one `ssh -t hostname` bit for each command line option except for the last one, and then to execute that list as a command.

```
#!/bin/sh

argn=$#
i=0

for arg do
   shift
   i=$(( i + 1 ))

   if [ "$i" -lt "$argn" ]; then
       set -- "$@" ssh -t "$arg"
   else
       set -- "$@" "/pathtofile/$arg/log.log"
   fi
done

command "$@"
```

Running this as

```
sh script.sh alpha beta gamma zeta
```

it would create the list

```
ssh -t alpha ssh -t beta ssh -t gamma /pathtofile/zeta/log.log
```

The last command in the script would execute this as a command.

The list is built in `$@`, the list of positional parameters, which at the start of the script contains the command line parameters of the script.  The loop keeps track of when the last element of that original list is encountered and treats it specially.

The `set` command, when used as above, will append to the list, and `shift` will remove the first element of the list (the one we are currently processing).

I'm sure this could be made shorter and more elegant with `zsh`-specific syntax.

Comment: I learned this just yesterday! `zsh -c 'set -- alpha beta gamma zeta; print -- "-t "${^@}'
`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, except that it would become like `"-t $1" "-t $2"...`. Using `o=-t; print -- "${(@)o:^^argv}"` would make it `"-t" "$1" "-t" "$2"`, but here you want `"ssh" "-t" "$1" "ssh" "-t" "$2"`, and actually even rather `ssh -t "$1" "ssh -t quoted-$2 \"...`

Comment: Where do you find a reference to the arcane incantations such as "$0" etc for these scripts?

Comment: @PeterNUnn I don't think I used `$0` in this script. Are you asking where to find more information about the `sh` shell? In that case, [I tend to read the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/) (specifically the "Shell & Utilities" section).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can easily get away without a loop:

```
cmd=()
for i ($argv[1,-2]) cmd+=(ssh -t $i)
$cmd tailf /pathtofile/$argv[-1]/log.log
```

Stritly speaking, since it's a shell command line that you pass to `ssh`, if you wanted to be able to support arbitrary values for those `$1`, `$2`, you'd need quote those arguments and add an extra level of quoting for each ssh.

Here assuming that the login shell of the user on all the hosts is Bourne-like:

```
cmd=(tailf /pathtofile/$argv[-1]/log.log)
argv[-1]=()
while (($#argv)) {
  cmd=(ssh -t "$argv[-1]" ${(j: :)${(qq)cmd}})
  argv[-1]=()
}
```

That should make it work when called as

```
that-script host1 host2 'dir with spaces and other nasty characters'
```